# Weird and mixed Gnome window theme

Tags: themes, archlinux, gnome

So I had dual DE installed on my Arch distro earlier, hated how the KDE couldn't transfer files at a decent speed and quit for Gnome.

During the period when I had KDE and Gnome on the system, the Gnome session has KDE properties in the window themes and the original Gnome one is just gone. Eventually, I removed both the Gnome and KDE with `pacman -Rcns plasma kde-applications` amd then `pacman -Rcns gnome gnome-extra`

After that I rebooted, installed gnome again with `pacman -Rcns gnome gnome-extras` Some weird things happened to the window. [The left one is settings, top right is chromium and bottom right is firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipp8k.png)

You see weird crosses in the window action buttons. Notjust that, command `ping` also yield 100% package lost, much like this one from this post: [Why "ping google.com" returns 100% packet loss if I am experiencing a perfect internet connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64175206/why-ping-google-com-returns-100-packet-loss-if-i-am-experiencing-a-perfect-in) But on arch linux this time.

Anyt help to fix these two problems would be appreciated, comment below if you need any more information, and thanks before hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try doing an `rm -rf ~/.config/*gtk*`.
This would remove all gtk files essentially resetting the themes back to default

Answer (score 0):

**First Problem -**

This is not a big problem you can go to https://www.gnome-look.org and install a new gtk theme.
GTK themes are responsible for window manager themes try installing and changing the default gtk theme from gnome tweaks.

**Second Problem -**

Try updating the system `sudo pacman -Syuu`.
Need more information about the system but this might help https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=199405

Comment: Indeed it did help me, by looking into the themes (that was not what i used eventually though, look at the reddit link below.) I also found out that the `systemd-networkd` being enabled was what caused the ping not to work. Thanks for the answer! I hope this can help others if you are also messing with DEs. And a note, you can also see this answer: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/k96ltr/help_needed_weird_and_mixed_gnome_window_theme/